# Undo --disallowedOperations with ROO MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

As part of a larger ROO based MVC project I have previously issued the following ROO command:

```
web mvc scaffold ~.domain.Yyy --class ~.web.YyyController --disallowedOperations update
```

Requirements have changed, and I now want to 'undo' the '--disallowedOperations' option; i.e I do want the update option for 'Yyy'.

I tried the following command:

```
web mvc scaffold ~.domain.Yyy --class ~.web.YyyController
```

Unfortunately ROO doesn't add the 'update' option automatically.

Creating 'update,jspx' and adding this to views.xml also didn't help.

How can I add the update option to the MVC based UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All the --disallowedOperations does is set those values to false in the annotation.

So, for instance, if I said --disallowedOperations delete,update,create, I would get the following put into my controller:

```
@RooWebScaffold(path = "myPath", formBackingObject = MyClass.class, create = false, 
                update = false, delete = false)
```

If I remove the "create = false", and the Roo Shell is running, then the magic of Roo shold recognize I removed it and re-generate the AspectJ files to now include the create method.  This comes directly from [their documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html), BTW.